# Arrow keys of keyboard not works in TextArea & Texbox after adding as tree item widget in gwt

Tags: gwt

Arrow keys of keyboard not works in TextArea and Texbox after adding as tree item widget in gwt

```
    public class TreeWidget implements EntryPoint {
          @Override
                public void onModuleLoad() {
                    VerticalPanel panel=new VerticalPanel();
                    TextArea textArea=new TextArea();
                    Tree tree=new Tree();
                    TreeItem item=new TreeItem();
                    item.addItem(textArea);
                    tree.addItem(item);
                    panel.add(tree);
                    RootPanel.get().add(panel);

                }}

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GWT Tree widgets swallow arrow keyboard events which make TextBoxes contained in TreeItems not respond to arrow keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770978/gwt-tree-widgets-swallow-arrow-keyboard-events-which-make-textboxes-contained-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think keyboard navigation of the tree is capturing key events.

You can disable it this way: create an instance of tree that doesn't use keyboard navigation. You must override the method that tells, for each treeitem, if keys are used or not.

Simplest way:

```
Tree tree = new Tree() {
  @Override
  public boolean isKeyboardNavigationEnabled(TreeItem currentItem) {
     return false; // no items will have key navigation
  }
};
```

If it works, then the problem is keyboard navigation. You can ask if the tree item is that with the textarea and `return false` to let the keyboard work for text.

Comment: Yes it is a problem with key events. thanks, problem is solved which I am facing. but it is stoping tree item event so what is a solution to work both.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if this method is checked for every key pressed, you could check if the item is the text one and if the textbox/area is focused or not. Return false if text is focused, and true otherwise.